# Scilab plot with many lines: automatic cycling trough 'LineSpec' styles

Tags: plot, colors, scilab

I am plotting around 10 Lines in the same plot and use the built-in option of `plot` to cycle through colors. Sadly, this option only has 7 colors and then starts with the first color again. Is there an option like in Matlab to get a  different line type, when the colors cycled through once?
I know I can change the color and line style manually for every line, but I would prefer an automatic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know a built-in way to do this, but reading the `Linespec` man page, you could create a function to cycle trough all specifiers.

The simplest of them being :

```
function Linespec=CycleSpec(n)
  // n : from 0 to N
  Linestyle =['-';'--';':';'-.']
  Linecolor = ['r';'g';'b';'c';'m';'y';'k';'w']
  Linemarker =['';'+';'o';'*';'.';'x';'s';'d';'^';'v';'>';'<';'p']
  i = modulo(n,size(Linecolor,'*'))+1
  j = modulo(floor(n/size(Linecolor,'*')),size(Linestyle,'*'))+1
  k = modulo(floor(n/size(Linecolor,'*')/size(Linestyle,'*')),size(Linemarker,'*'))+1
  Linespec = Linestyle(j)+Linecolor(i)+Linemarker(k)
endfunction
```

Which could be use as

```
figure(1)
for n=0:40
  plot(x,x+n,CycleSpec(n))
end
```

And if you really want something simple, we can add a global variable storing the counter so you only need to call the function, no need for parameter

```
function Linespec=CycleSpec()
  // n : from 0 to N
  global CycleSpecCounter
  if CycleSpecCounter==[] then
    CycleSpecCounter = 0
  end
  n=CycleSpecCounter
  [...] same code as before [...]
  CycleSpecCounter=CycleSpecCounter+1
endfunction
```

and you'd only need to type

```
plot(x,x+n,CycleSpec())
```